# How do I get the counter for facebook share button to show all the time?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, twitter

I have a twitter share button and a facebook share button in my blog page. The twitter counter always shows, but the facebook one only shows when you post something, and then goes away when the page is refreshed and does not show up again until something is posted. I want it to show all the time as to adhere to design cohesiveness.

```
           <div id="share_stuff">
                <div class="share_buttons">
                    <a name="fb_share" type="box_count" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
                </div>
                <div class="share_buttons">
                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://tweetmeme.com/i/scripts/button.js"></script>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page needs to be shared at least 3 times before the counter appears.

More information can be found here:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Talk:Facebook_Share#Counter_only_displays_on_interaction

Answer (score 0):

From what i can tell the official facebook share works in the way you have described above by design.  If you use http://www.fbshare.me instead it will show you the count on page load etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
http://addthis.com

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it for me was to add a css rule above your button:

```
<style>
  .fb_share_no_count {
    display: block !important;
  }
</style>
<div>
  <a name="fb_share" type="box_count" expr:share_url="data:post.url" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a><script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This blog has the answer, you have to hack the FB.Share JS file and change one parameter, I can vouch this works as of this writing.

http://kopepasah.com/social-media/facebook/facebook-share-count-button/